# How to create in ASP.Net Core specific URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to create route like `site.net/query`?

Attention, not

> site.net/?q=querystring

What I want is:

> site.net/querystring

I tried something like this, but this don't work

```
[Route("")]
class MyController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet]
  public string Get()
  {
    return Request.QueryString.ToString();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put that path in the routing string:

```
[HttpGet("/Something/[action]/{q}")]
public string Get(string q)
{
    return q;
}
```

When you access this link: `localhost/Something/Get/mynicestring`

`mynicestring` will be shown